# Exception on inserting into Access 2010 in C Sharp

Tags: c#, ms-access, exception

I am getting this exception when inserting into a Access 2010 database.

Example, the following :

```
INSERT INTO CranbrookMain (
       ID,BlockNo,Plot,SubPlot,Code,Type,LastName,FirstName,
       ServiceHome,ServiceAddress,ServiceCity,
       Notes
) VALUES (
       '1','Y','37','DS','C2','O','SMITH','John',
       'Service Inc.','520B SLATER ROAD N.W.','CityName',
       'CityName                          ☺    '
)
```

Results in the exception:

```
Ex: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): 
Syntax error in string in query expression ''CityName                          ☺'.
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at ReadingData.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ReadingData\ReadingData\Program.cs:line 238
```

The code that executes the SQL insert query is:

```
insertSQL = "INSERT INTO CranbrookMain (ID,BlockNo,Plot,SubPlot,Code,Type,LastName," +
            "FirstName,ServiceHome,ServiceAddress,ServiceCity,Notes) VALUES (" +
            "'"+id+ "','" + blockNo + "','" + plot + "','" + subPlot + "','" + code + 
            "','" + type + "','" + lastname + "','" + firstname + "','" + serviceHome +
            "','" + serviceAddress + "','" + serviceCity + "','" + notes +"')";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(insertSQL, con); // creating query command
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The error occurs in `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` function call.

The above SQL INSERT statement works fine if I directly execute in the Access 2010 file.

Comment: Whats the sad face smiley doing near your city name?

Comment: Thats from the file which has binary data in it.

Comment: File??? Yo are passing a file for city??

Answer (score 1):

Use parameterized queries and you won't have this issue, nor will you be exposed to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

As *RedFilter* said, you should not construct your SQL the way you're doing it.
The issue is that your `Notes` field contains data that is not properly represented in a way that can be parsed by the database driver.

What do you think will happen if any of your values contains apostrophes?
Say for instance, you're trying to save a record for `Mr O'Reilly` living on `22 Queen's Road`)?
You'll either get garbage in your database or you will get exceptions, or, much worse, someone could easily [inject some SQL and hack your database](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Instead, do something like:

```
insertSQL = "INSERT INTO CranbrookMain (ID,BlockNo,Plot,SubPlot,Code,Type,"
          + "LastName,FirstName,ServiceHome,ServiceAddress,ServiceCity,Notes) "
          + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(insertSQL, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = id;
cmd.Parameters.Add("BlockNo", OleDbType.Char, 2).Value = blockNo;
cmd.Parameters.Add("Plot", OleDbType.Char, 3).Value = plot;
cmd.Parameters.Add("SubPlot", OleDbType.Char, 3).Value = subPlot;
cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", OleDbType.Char, 3).Value = code;
cmd.Parameters.Add("Type", OleDbType.Char, 3).Value = type;
cmd.Parameters.Add("LastName",OleDbType.Char, 50).Value = lastname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("FirstName", OleDbType.Char, 64).Value = firstname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("ServiceHome", OleDbType.Char, 50).Value = serviceHome;
cmd.Parameters.Add("ServiceAddress", OleDbType.Char, 128).Value = serviceAddress;
cmd.Parameters.Add("ServiceCity", OleDbType.Char, 50).Value = serviceCity;
cmd.Parameters.Add("Notes", OleDbType.Char, 255).Value = notes;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: +1 @RedFilter gave the answer, you provided the code example for it

Answer (score 0):

```
  ''CityName                          ☺'
```

It looks like your notes variable contains an apostophe >'< making your SQL invalid 
something like

```
  notes = "'CityName                          ☺"
```

As @RedFilter and @Renaud Bompuis said "Use parameterized queries" instead of concatenating strings